# android custom permission not shown on install page

Tags: android, permissions, authorization

I created a custom permission in one of my app and published in the market, but i noticed that while installing the app the custom permission are not shown on the install page, please suggest whats going wrong in it.

thank in advance

Comment: Please any one with the answer?

Comment: If you paste your Android Manifest here (at least all relevant parts), it would be possible to help you